# Stretch parent div if child div is bigger

Tags: html, css

I have the following site structure:

```
<body class="body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="header" />
        <div class="content" />
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my css code:

```
.body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 900px;
}

.header {
    min-height: 60px;
    padding: 30px 30px 0;
}

.content {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

In my content div, I have a quite long text. The problem is, that the text is bigger than the visible area of the browser, but no scroll bar is shown, so it seems to me as if the content div is not being stretched in order to show all of its content.

How can I achiev the latter?

Comment: You are specifying `overflow: hidden;` so that is what it does, try a different type of overflow.

Comment: you forgot to add `</div>` tag. demo - http://jsfiddle.net/vgsnqq0v/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `overflow:hidden` and add `overflow:auto` for the body class. Also missing close `"` in the body class.

```
.body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
overflow:auto;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lrms59e/)